# ComboxEdit that display many members of ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, mvvm, devexpress

I want to display data in a ComboBoxEdit; 
for example I have a model that contains

```
public class Foo 
{
public long Id{get ; set ;} 
public string FirstName {get ; set ;}  
public string LastName{get ; set ;}  
public string Town {get ; set ;}  

}
```

I have an observableCollection that contains many rows of that Model.
In the view, I want to display a ComboBoxEdit showing the FirstName and LastName with a ColumnFilter also. What else could be used?

All examples are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried to use ...  `override string ToString ()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a LookUpEdit instead:

```
<Window ...
    xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid" 
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyNamespace" 
    ...>
<Window.Resources>
<Window.Resources>
    <my:myObservableCollection x:Key="myObservableCollection" />
</Window.Resources>
...
<dxg:LookUpEdit AutoPopulateColumns="False" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data, Source={StaticResource myObservableCollection}}" 
    ValueMember="Id" DisplayMember="Id">
    <dxg:LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <dxg:GridControl Name="PART_GridControl">
                <dxg:GridControl.Columns >
                    <dxg:GridColumn Header="First name" FieldName="FirstName" VisibleIndex="0"/>
                    <dxg:GridColumn Header="Last name" FieldName="LastName" VisibleIndex="1" />
                </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            </dxg:GridControl>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </dxg:LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate>
</dxg:LookUpEdit>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just override ToString() function on object and and when the component (not only combobox) wants use a description of the object then uses ToString ()

```
  public class Foo
  {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
      string ret = FirstName + " " + LastName;
      return ret;
    }
  }
```

If you meant otherwise, write more details please.